# Invalid Filter Error when accessing member profile

Tags: error

I get this error trying to access a profile in Civi - hasn't happened with any other profile. Please help! This is a major donor and I cannot access their info

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Invalid Filter"

Comment: Hi Kari - i expect someone can help but will need some more information from you (without you giving away too much detail). Eg when you say "trying to access a profile in Civi" what exactly do you mean. a 'profile' in civi is a specific thing. do you just mean 'a contact record'. if not, perhaps you can provide a link (without your domain) to help shed light on this

Comment: Thank you for your question, I am new to this and this is our first issue. I am inputting donor contributions and this error pops up with one specific donors contact profile (maybe profile isn't the correct term).